# When would you use spies over doubles in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I can understand the application of test doubles in Rspec. You might want to test a method, which has an object that performs an expensive network query. So you use a fill-in (the test double) to return a value that you need from the expensive operation:

```
class Contact
  def update
    @api_result = AmazonAPI.perform_expensive_task
    self.status = @api_result['status']
    self.last_checked = @api_result['last_checked']
    save!
  end
end

describe Contact do
  subject { Contact.new }

  describe '#update' do
    it "updates contact with api criteria" do 
      api = double('Amazon API')
      allow(api).to receive(:perform_expensive_task).and_return({ status: 1, last_checked: Time.now })
      subject.update
      expect(subject.status).to eq 1
    end
  end
end
```

We need to test the update method, but we do not want to test the API query. So we use a test double and stub it, to work around the requirement.

But then I come across spies. And I see no use case for this. This is the example provided in the tutorial:

```
let(:order) do
  spy('Order', process_line_items: nil, charge_credit_card: true, send_email: true)
end

before(:example) do
  order.process_line_items
  order.charge_credit_card
  order.send_email
end

it 'calls #process_line_items on the order' do
  expect(order).to have_received(:process_line_items)
end

it 'calls #charge_credit_card on the order' do
  expect(order).to have_received(:charge_credit_card)
end

it 'calls #send_email on the order' do
  expect(order).to have_received(:send_email)
end
```

This specific example explicitly calls the three methods it later checks whether it called. Of course, it called them. It did it right in the test. In real situations, when should I use spies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A spy tracks the calls that are made onto it (the messages it is sent, specifically). So you use a spy whenever you need to assert that a specific call is made on a collaborator.

The typical use case is to check that your implementation is/isn’t using the external collaborator depending on input. Say you intend to conditionally log, or you might check that a job is enqueued with specific arguments, or a certain mailer method is called...

Spies are the tool to guarantee that your objects are cooperating correctly.

*UPDATE*

Examples can be found in @meta's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52717158/384417.

A simple use case with code is the logger one:

```
class SomeCommand
  def call(arg:, other:)
    if arg <= 0
      logger.warn("args should be positive")
    else
      logger.debug("all fine")
    end
    # more
  end

  def logger
    Rails.logger # for instance
  end
end

describe SomeCommand
  let(:logger) { spy('Logger') }

  # replace collaborator
  before { allow(subject).to receive(:logger) { logger } }

  context 'with negative value' do
    it 'warns' do
      subject.call(arg: -1, other: 6)
      expect(logger).to have_received(:warn)
      expect(logger).not_to have_received(:debug)
    end
  end

  context 'with positive value' do
    it 'logs as debug' do
      subject.call(arg: 1, other: 6)
      expect(logger).not_to have_received(:warn)
      expect(logger).to have_received(:debug)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add one more case on top what [rewritten wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52710713/299774)

Spies give you some flexibility. If you need to check that the method was called you can do it with mocks in a before:

```
before do
  expect(foo).to receive(:do_stuff)
end

specify do
  bar.run
end
```

But `before` is not the best place to add expectations. You're [supposed to separate setup, run and test stages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Test_structure). You can do this:

```
specify do 
  expect(foo).to receive(:do_stuff)
  bar.run
end
```

But it looks better to do

```
before do
  bar.run
end

specify do
  expect(foo).to have_received(:do_stuff)
end
```

You'd have cleaner code when there's more stuff to check

```
before { bar.run }

specify do
  expect(foo).to have_received(:do_stuff)
end

context 'with some special conditions' do
  before { set_up_special_conditions }

  specify do
    expect(foo).not_to have_received(:do_stuff)
  end
end
```

It's maybe not a big deal, and you could still live with

```
specify do
  bar.run
  expect(foo).to have_received(:do_stuff)
end

context 'with some special conditions' do
  before { set_up_special_conditions } # * check the note at the bottom

  specify do
    bar.run
    expect(foo).not_to have_received(:do_stuff)
  end
end
```

But I think a good approach to define contexts is to have only essential differences (`set_up_special_conditions` and `expect(foo).not_to have_received(:do_stuff)` in the example) explicitly mentioned. Whatever is not different than the context "above" should not appear in more specific context "below". It helps with managing bigger specs.

*Note: I'm not sure about the order of the `before` blocks defined this way, and after looking at [rspec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) I'm not sure this order is guaranteed. Can't check right that moment. But for just for demonstration purposes we can pretend that `before { set_up_special_conditions }` will run before `before { bar.run }`. But if that's not the case - there are other ways to ensure that, but it seems outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: "You can't set what spy is returning" this is not completely correct. You can set up responses on a spy the same way you set up responses on a double, using `allow(spy).to_receive(:msg)` using whatever response configuration mechanism. Documentation in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/configuring-responses

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. What I meant was that with this interface you (obviously) can't do stuff like this `.to have_received().and_returned(something)`

Comment: Well you indeed can, on partial doubles. Pure spies are not backed with an original implementation. If you need to check the original impelmentation, you have to do `allow(partial).to receive(:msg).and_wrap_original { |m, *args| m.call(*args).tap { |resp| @resp = resp } }`. Then you can `expect(@resp).to something` after you have called it. Again, this is not a spy, but a partial doouble with wrapping.